# How to save in Core Data with ID?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, relational-database, relationship

I need change "ignition" in coreData of the id specified, but i can't use predicates.

```
func saveIgnition(){
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectNo == %@", oDriver.sObjectNo)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key:"objectNo", ascending:true)
    print(oDriver.sObjectNo)
    print("is 0 o 1: ", oDriver.iIgnition)
    // we set up our entity by selecting the entity and context that we're targeting
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Driver", into: oMain.moc)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Driver")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    entity.setValue(self.oDriver.iIgnition, forKey: "ignition")
    do {
        try oMain.moc.save()
        fetchIgn()

    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is 'oDriver.sObjectNo' a string or int?

Comment: What problem are you having? What do you mean you can't use predicates when your code is using a predicate?